# Rails datetime value changes while saving data with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, timezone

I am getting a date value with Time.zone.now .
Then I am updating data in sql server with activerecord but activerecord does not get that value and uses UTC time. Is there a way to save data with my timezone in activerecord

Comment: What's your time zone? How does it compare to the `config.active_record.default_timezone` setting?

Comment: If your application is intended to work in London region, add `config.time_zone = 'London'` in `application.rb` file. Refer below link for in-depth knowledge!!

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: Time.zone.now creates my current time in my zone which defined in config. problem  occurs when I try to update database. database gets UTC time